# Find Most Recent Entry for an Intersection of Categories

Tags: sql, mysql, date

I know there are a number of "How do I find the most recent record" questions out there, but none of them quite solved my particular problem: in MySQL, I'm trying to find the most recent record for an entry that's mapped to two different categories in the same table. There's essentially an ENTRIES table with a bunch of info, a CATEGORIES table (id, name) and a ENTRY_CATEGORIES table (entry_id, category_id). I need to find the most recent record that's mapped to two different categories. I've managed to do it, but only by essentially joining a derived table on itself and it feels like there's a cleaner way to do this. How can I better express the following mess:

```
SELECT doc.entry_id
FROM exp_category_posts doc 
INNER JOIN exp_category_posts fund ON doc.entry_id = fund.entry_id 
INNER JOIN exp_weblog_titles t ON doc.entry_id = t.entry_id
WHERE doc.cat_id = 408 
AND fund.cat_id = 548 
AND t.entry_date = (SELECT MAX(t.entry_date)
FROM exp_category_posts doc 
INNER JOIN exp_category_posts fund ON doc.entry_id = fund.entry_id 
INNER JOIN exp_weblog_titles t ON doc.entry_id = t.entry_id
WHERE doc.cat_id = 408 
AND fund.cat_id = 548)
```

It's a hard-coded example where 408 and 548 would normally be fields as well. This is an Expression Engine database, if you're curious.

Answer (score 1):

You might try replacing

```
AND t.entry_date = (SELECT MAX(t.entry_date)
FROM exp_category_posts doc 
INNER JOIN exp_category_posts fund ON doc.entry_id = fund.entry_id 
INNER JOIN exp_weblog_titles t ON doc.entry_id = t.entry_id
WHERE doc.cat_id = 408 
AND fund.cat_id = 548)
```

with:

```
ORDER BY t.entry_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The optimizer will probably end up with a similar query in the end (that's not guaranteed, of course, but it's fairly likely), but the query is half as long.  You'd have to run `explain` and profile a few `select` queries to see if it performs as well or better.

Comment: I'd love to, but this version of MySQL won't allow a LIMIT statement in a subquery. Should have mentioned that, sorry.